# Grails: Audit plugin: dateCreated has different value than stored in database

Tags: grails, transactions, grails-orm, flush, audit

I have used "org.grails.plugins:audit-logging:3.0.5" plugin. There's a table named User and I have to take its exact dateCreated value (automatically populated from plugin) and send it into SQS message. However different value in seconds is sent. Here's my code:

```
User user = new User()
user.status = "something"
def newUser = user.save(failOnError: true, flush: true)
msgBody.timeStamp = newUser.dateCreated
```

If there's **2020-09-14 20:44:58** dateCreated in database, **2020-09-14 20:44:57** is being sent in msgBody. Please help.

msgBody is an object sent from frontend(angularjs) to backend as JSON.

Comment: "2020-09-14 20:44:57 is being sent in msgBody" - How is the message body being created?

Comment: msgBody is sent from frontend (angularjs) to backend as JSON including other details I want to add in SQS message.